# Trouble using a DLL in C#

Tags: c#, dll

I'm using VS Express 2010 express. This is the very first time I tried to create and use my own DLL.
Initially I built a one-project solution (no DLL) that ran fine, and then was asked to put one of the most important classes (call it ClassZ) into a DLL, so our customer would not see all of our code.
So I added a new project to the solution and made it a class library. Then I cut and pasted the class ClassZ to the new class library project. Then I think I successfully added a reference from the main project (a console application) to that class library project. Everything is in the same namespace NS1.

But now build gives me all sorts of error messages that look like this (I'm translating the messages from French):

Error  The overloaded method best corresponding to 'NS1.ClassZ.Method1(byte[], ushort, out ushort, ref NS1.ClassA) has invalid arguments

Error Impossible to convert between ref NS1.ClassA [.source filepath here...]  and ref  NS1.ClassA [ ... DLL file path here...]

In other words every one of my calls to the methods of the class library generate an error. By the way they are all declared as static methods.

Comment: It sounds like you have the same class in two projects.  Don't do that.

Comment: "I was asked to put one of the most important classes (call it ClassZ) into a DLL, so our customer would not see all of our code"  This will not stop them from seeing the code (or at least a decent representation) - .NET DLLs are very easy to decompile.

Comment: If you are worried about customers "seeing" your code you need to look into obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks to Slaks, 
Yes I had a copy of ClassA in both projects. This is a leftover from my C++ practice where I would copy the header file into several projects! The class looked like a header file.